# C++ Ensure class instance throw exception when expected

Tags: c++, error-handling

EDIT: Code provided works. Error was memory leak in destructor.

How do I test that an error is thrown when expected? I get "Abort trap: 6" when I run this code. What am I missing?

Inside my Class I got this function:

```
Stack::pop()
{
    if (top == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("stack is empty");
    }
    else
    ...
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    Stack s{};
    try
    {
        s.pop();
    }
    catch (logic_error& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Continue run code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Code looks good to me, but it's incomplete, so presumably the error is in the code you left out.

Comment: Have you ever heard of unit testing? Write tests that call your code in all kind of ways including ways that trigger this error and then check this exception is thrown.

Comment: Work as expected [here](https://godbolt.org/z/abvhG1fTf).

Comment: Better to catch by **`const`** reference BTW.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in the destructor.